# Strange output while Looping through localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to insert items into the localStorage and loop through it this is the code

```
localStorage.setItem(1,'Lorem');
localStorage.setItem(2,'Ipsum');
localStorage.setItem(3,'Dolor');
for(var i in window.localStorage){
    console.log(i);
}
```

this is what I get as output on Firefox it seems to work fine on Chrome

```
3
2
1
key
getItem
setItem
removeItem
clear
length
```

the output seems to be the 3 values + the functions and length of the local storage I only want to output my values.
A for localstorage.length loop cant be used because I plan to insert and delete values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if it's not a property inherted from the object, like length, prototyped functions, etc...
So you need to call hasOwnProperty on the object, before continuing on the object.

```
for(var i in window.localStorage){
   if(window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(i);
   }

}
```

Comment: is there a reason why this is needed in Firefox and not in chrome?

Comment: Chrome probaly strives to make the lives of developers easier, whilst the firefox implementation is the more correct one. https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in `The loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype (properties closer to the object in the prototype chain override prototypes' properties).`. A year ago the firefox behaviour was also present in chrome. They must have changed it recently.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to how Objects are being looped. You need to loop through the `Object.hasOwnProperty`:

```
localStorage.setItem(1, 'Lorem');
localStorage.setItem(2, 'Ipsum');
localStorage.setItem(3, 'Dolor');
for (var i in window.localStorage) {
  if (window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty( i ))
    console.log(i);
}
```

I am really surprised how you got that output, as when I tried with Chrome, I got this:

[image: preview]

Comment: it only occures in firefox

Comment: You can also do Object.values(localStorage)